# Stable and unstable manifolds that are tangent to each other in a continuous dynamical system?

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, intuition

I am thinking of a scenario/ examples where the stable and unstable manifold of an equilibrium of a continuous dynamical system are tangent to each other?

Any examples/ plots would be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward example is a planar system with a homoclinic orbit, say
\begin{align}
\dot{x} = y,\\
\dot{y} = x - x^2.
\end{align}
The unstable and stable manifolds of the origin in the right half plane coincide, and hence are tangent.